# How to repent for stealing in my childhood?

Tags: tawba, theft

I stole when I was very young, most when I was below puberty, so I am forgiven by default, but do I still have to make up for it?

I even stole after I passed puberty, but still very young, now assuming (obviously) I am at sin, and I must repent sincerely, how am I supposed to compensate who I stole from as I use to steal small chocolates and sweets of various shops and I've forgotten which. I stole off someone I know but have no contact with, and another I do know, but I feel embarrassed to admit to it.

Can I just give charity equal if not greater to that value and hope that deed goes to them, as it will solve the problem I forgot how many shops I stole from I feel embarrassed confronting them to forgive me etc. I even stole when I was young gloves of a clothes company, what do I do there? Go up to the CEO and say "forgive me for the glove I stole", I am repentful by Allah but find it difficult to compensate for it physically due to these barriers. But am aware if I dong compensate that particular person I wronged can drag me to hell fire. Please shed some light.

Comment: Why don't you buy chocolates and sweets from the shops you've visited but after the purchase tell them to keep what you bought? this way they can re sell it and you would have paid for what you've done!

Answer (score 2):

As a general Islamic rule, (even if you stole something before the age of puberty), a person who has stolen something, he/she is Zamen (responsible) for the thing that has stolen. Actually he ought to give back it to its owner. In the case that the thing (money or...) has missed, it ought to be given to them at the same amount of the thing which has been stolen. If he (you) couldn’t find its owner,  then give it to his heir. And in the case that he (you) couldn’t find his heir, in accordance with Ehtiat (caution),  give it as Sadaqah (charity) to the poor person who is not Seyyed (with the permission of the Hakim of Sharia or his agent). Hence you ought to give them back to their owner even if you shy…

Of course I suggest you that do it indirectly (if you assume there could be some problems if you give them back directly…). Hopefully it could be relatively a good response for you (in a nutshell)

---

**Reference**:

- [www.porsojoo.com](http://www.porsojoo.com/fa/node/50753)