# Can I give sadaqah for stealing as repentance

Tags: tawba

Salam
I stole some money from someone from my family in my childhood 8-9years old
And now I’m 18  all I think about is the sin I have committed since I have grown up I thought about telling my mom about it so she can pay it back for me but the thing is we have family problems between my mom and the one I stole money from them
And now I don’t work I don’t know where I should bring the money from
What should I really do?

Comment: Depending on the relationship status stealing from a family member is not punished. Mainly these are cases between parents and their children. Else you must in first place ask for forgiveness from the person you've done wrong.

Comment: Can I just pay them back the amount I have stolen from them?

Comment: I don’t have the ability to ask for forgiveness from them:(

Comment: Check out the answer from this question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18807/how-to-repent-for-stealing-in-my-childhood?rq=1